List the processes being killed by org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchDog
I have a Java based application based on org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.
To ensusre that the commands being run are destroyed after a specific timeout, I am attaching org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchDog to it.
I want to list down the processes being destroyed by WatchDog as part of some troubleshooting. How do I do that?

This could should normally show you processes destroyed.
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchdog;

public class CustomExecuteWatchdog extends ExecuteWatchdog {

public CustomExecuteWatchdog(long timeout) {
    super(timeout);
}

@Override
public synchronized void destroyProcess() {
    // Before destroying, log the process details
    if (super.killedProcess()) {
        // Assuming you can somehow retrieve process details
        System.out.println("Terminating process: [Process Information Here]");
    }
    super.destroyProcess();
}

}

// Assuming you can somehow retrieve process details -- precisely what I am looking for
